# How to include arrows with text in a 3d figure?

Tags: matlab, 3d, matlab-figure

I have a box, but I would like to include different things so that it becomes a box with arrows representing stresses included on the box. Therefore, my question is the following:

- Is it possible to create several arrows in the box with text on them, to represent stresses on the box? And if this is possible, is it also possible to use greek letters with subscript?
- Is it possible to include the greek letters with subscript from latex?

The current code I am using is the:

```
    x=[
 0 2 2 0 0 
 0 2 2 0 0 
 0 0 0 0 0 
 2 2 2 2 2 
];
y=[
 0 0 2 2 0
 0 0 2 2 0
 0 2 2 0 0
 0 2 2 0 0
];
z=[
 0 0 0 0 0
 2 2 2 2 2
 0 0 2 2 0
 0 0 2 2 0
];

x1=[0 1];
y1=[0 1];
z1=[0 1];
 figure;
line(x',y',z');
 view(3);
```

Comment: I dont think there is a standard way of doing this. Try the FileExchange. https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25372-marrow3-m-easy-to-use-3d-arrow or https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/12274-3d-arrow-with-many-color-parameter-options

Comment: Okay, thank your reply!

Answer (score 0):

For the Greek letters in subscript with latex, you can just use it as follows:

```
figure (1); clf;
plot(rand(100,1))
title('Greek Letters: {\omega}_{\alpha}^{\beta}')
```

[image: Matlab figure with Greek letters in subscript and superscript]

As for the arrow with text, this matlab file center file might help:
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/278-arrow